# cannot Install a pyhton package

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I want to install the package existing in this repository in my anaconda enviroment
https://github.com/ChrisCummins/ProGraML

they say to use the command 'pip install -U programl'
but I keep getting this error

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement programl (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for programl

I have tried updating pip, creating another environment, cloning the programl repository and downloading the requirements.txt but to no result

I can't figure out what I'm missing

Comment: What python version do you have?

Comment: @thatrandomperson 3.9.13

Comment: It's just try `pip install programl` ---Here is the orginal repo https://pypi.org/project/programl/

Comment: @Bhargav tried, but still the same error :(

Comment: ahh are you uisng windows? I've just seen the documentation. Seems like it only build for `Linux` & `Mac`...Not windows.

Comment: @Bhargav yes I am using windows, can't believe I missed that part, thank you very much I'll try using mac